# PowerShell Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

Tags: excel, powershell

Any help is welcome. 
I'm using PowerShell to manipulate an Excel sheet. For some reason this works.

```
    for($o = 1; $o -le $firstRowMes.Length + $dagenInDeMaand; $o++){
if($o -ne $exception)
{

    $ws.Cells.Item($o, 3) = $firstRowMes[$index]
    $ws.Cells.Item($o, 4) = $betweenMes[$index]
    $ws.Cells.Item($o, 5) = $Lastmes[$index]
    $ws.Cells.Item($o, 7) = "=C" + $o + "/F" + $o
    $ws.Cells.Item($o, 6) = "=SUM(C" + $o + ":E" + $o + ")"
    $index++
}
else
{
    $exception = ($exception + $applicationArray.Length +1)
}
}
```

But this doesn't

```
for($g = 1; $g -le $applicationArray.Length;$g++){
$index = 2
$begintrendGetallen = ""
for($i = 0; $i -le $eerstePeriode-1; $i++){
   $begintrendGetallen = $begintrendGetallen +  "G" + (1+$g+(9*$i)).ToString() + ";"    
}
$ws.Cells.Item($index, 11).Formula = "=AVERAGE(" + $begintrendGetallen + ")"
$index++
}
```

If I directly insert the output into excel it works fine. 
The full error I'm getting is this:

> Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC At
>   C:\Users\yniasr\Documents\Argenta\Autoreportdagen.ps1:202 char:5
>   +     $ws.Cells.Item($index, 11).Formula = "=AVERAGE(" + $begintrendGet ...
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

I saw some posts about it here but none of their solutions applies for my code.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect caused by trailing `;` in your formula. Try to use `$begintrendGetallen.trim(";")`

Your index initialization should be outside of the loop. Otherwise it is being re-set to `2` whenever the loop runs.

```
$index = 2
for($g = 1; $g -le $applicationArray.Length;$g++){

    $begintrendGetallen = ""

    for($i = 0; $i -le $eerstePeriode-1; $i++){
       $begintrendGetallen = $begintrendGetallen +  "G" + (1+$g+(9*$i)).ToString() + ";"    
    }

    $begintrendGetallen = $begintrendGetallen.trim(";")

    $ws.Cells.Item($index, 11).Formula = "=AVERAGE(" + $begintrendGetallen + ")"
    $index++
}
```

`$i=0` is jarring when dealing with PowerShell/Excel as often run into issues with Excel using non-zero arrays. I *think* it's not causing any issues in your code though.